# How to replace occurrences with javascript inside delimiters?

Tags: javascript

How to replace all occurrences that are within two characters. 
Example:

```
I love :octocat: beach and you do :joy: not like it
```

Replace with a url that will be generated based on what's inside the delimiters

```
I love [img of octocat] beach and you do [img of joy] not like it
```

Javascript needs to capture what's inside : and replace

I've tried several things without success. can anybody help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you looked into regular expressions? Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Is not repeated. Need to replace text that are between delimiter characters. I do not know what's inside the delimiters. I simply need to take what's inside and replace it with something else.

Comment: @DaniloSantos what is `something else`? Care to eleborate?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I am still studying. I'm going to fix it

Comment: Well I mean you say you want to replace it with something else, but in order to find a good solution we need to know what you are replacing with.

Comment: I'm going to replace it with an img. They are emoji. I need to capture what's between : : mount a url and display an image;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky for you `String.prototype.replace` accepts a RegExp and a function. So, in your example you can write a regex to find strings between 2 characters and replace them.

The RegEx for your example using colons would simply be `/:(.*?):/g`, and you could do whatever you want in your function, e.g. replace the string with the string + additional characters. e.g.

```
var str = "I love :octocat: beach and you do :joy: not like it"
str = str.replace(/:(.*?):/ig, function (str){
  return str + 'BLAHBLAHBLAH'
})
```

The value of `str` is now `"I love :octocat:BLAHBLAHBLAH beach and you do :joy:BLAHBLAHBLAH not like it"`, fun stuff eh?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback function querying a map `{'pattern': 'replacement'}`:

```js
let str = 'I love :octocat: beach and you do :joy: not like it';

let replacements = {
  'octocat': '[img of octocat]',
  'joy': '[img of joy]'
};

let result = str.replace(/:(\w+):/g, (match, word) => replacements[word]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shrtfrm:

```
"I love :octocat: beach and you do :joy: not like it".split(":").map((el,i)=>i%2===0?el:{"octocat":"hello","joy":"test"}[el]||el).join("");
```

Simply split, replace and join again.

http://jsbin.com/moxexilica/edit?console

Explanation:

```
.split(":")
//returns: ["I love ","octocat"," beach and you do ","joy"," not like it"]
.map((el,i)=>i%2===0?el
//leave the strings outside (indexes 0,2,4) as they are
:el{"octocat":"hello","joy":"test"}[el]
//replace the others (indexes 1,3) with the value in the object so:
// octocat => hello
//joy => test
||el
//if it does not exist e. g. ':test:' fall back to 'test'
//now weve got:
//["I love ","hello"," beach and you do ","test"," not like it"]
.join("")
//a string
```

Extracted to a function:

```
function replace(str,replacer){
  return str.split(":").map((el,i)=>i%2===0?el:replacer[el]||el).join("");
}
```

So you can do:

```
alert(replace("I love :octocat: beach and you do :joy: not like it", {octocat:"manly",joy:"not"}));
```

With images:

```
document.body.innerHTML=replace(document.body.innerHTML, {octocat:"<img src='octocat.png' />",joy:"<img src='joy.png' />"});
```

Note that ":" is not a good delemiter. You may use a more uncommon one like %% or !! ...

Comment: This is incredibly hard to maintain and lots of hardcoding, I don't think this is a good answer for this question.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet why? you can move the replace object out of it and put it into a function?

Comment: Doesn't work when the string contains extra colons (or whatever the delimiter is), e.g. `He told me: the :octocat: is full of :joy:`

Comment: @martias that applies to every textinline syntax. Did you ever tried to put <?php somewhere into you php file just for fun? However i admit the user should use another delemiter...

Comment: @James shure. However, looks like the OP already has found an answer, wich is quite strange as i think its not what he wanted... :/